# How to run Scalatest with JUnit tests using maven plugin

Tags: scala, maven, junit, scalatest, maven-surefire-plugin

I am writing some tests using scala to java maven project . I want to run those tests with the maven plugin but I want also that the rest of the JUnit tests will run run as well .
The problem is that according to [this guidelines](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin)  I have to disable surefire .
I there a solution for running both scalatest and junit tests ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run your scalatests using the maven surefire plugin. You simply have to specify to use the `JUnitRunner` via an annotation to run your scalatest with.

```scala
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyTest extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  test("foobar") {
    true should be(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to configure scalatest running in this case? e.g. make sure there is a reporter or configuring tags?

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you need to annotate your specs to use the JUnit runner.

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyTest extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  test("foobar") {
    true should be(true)
  }
}
```

You also need to configure the surefire plugin to include the specs. Here is my config:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Test.*</include>
      <include>**/*Specification.*</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Be sure to add any patterns to the includes to match your test class names.

Don't forget to bring in scalatest from [maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest)